# Postgresql: how to change the table definition

Tags: mysql, postgresql

The problem: I'm searching for an alternative solution to change column definition in `postgresql`.

I would like to do something that is similar to the mysql solution:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name column_definition
```

Is there a way to use *CHANGE COLUMN* similar to what I've described previously? Is there any way to easily change the column definition in postgres?

I'd like to use a similar method to my example because I'm building the alter query from code.

Comment: That's its just the syntax difference between the two databases. 
To solve that you might have to write an abstraction layer which is database aware and able to define which syntax to use depending on your database.

Comment: Why not to use `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME COLUMN ...` and `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN TYPE ...`?

Comment: @mantigatos Yes you're right. The fact is that I'm writing that abstraction layer. You're right I could use those alter queries you've wrote. I've also managed to solve the problem. First I've dropped the column and then re-added with the new definition. However if someone uses my solution he might be aware that the data in that field will be lost. In my case it is okay to do so, because I'm using this for database migration and I'm adding the data after the db structure has been modified.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What's wrong with PostgreSQL's `ALTER TABLE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to MySQL's `CHANGE COLUMN` clause in PostgreSQL. You'll need to specify the column definitions parts one by one. See documentation for [ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-altertable.html). Fortunately you don't need to detect differences between old definition and new in typical cases, if the change is redundant  PostgreSQL will just ignore it. e.g `ALTER COLUMN x DROP NOT NULL` will still work when the column is already nullable.